# read output log file, and print all unique file paths using bash/python script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, bash

From below output log file, I want to print all unique file paths ( e.g. /AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV ) using bash/python script

OS Platform: Linux

**Here's the Output log file (output.log):**

```
/AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV:    google.service.instance = https://aoodev.com (ms: azure_mico, cs: docker_telco)
/AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/QA1:    yahoo.service.instance = aoodit.com (ms: yahoo_mico, cs: yahoo_telco)
/AWS Cloud/Test/Blender/Service/QA1:    google.service.instance = aoodev.com (ms: azure_mico, cs: google_telco)
/AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/QA1:    yahoo.service.instance = aoodqa.com
/Azure Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV:    google.service.instance = aoodev.com
/Azure Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/QA1:    https://yahoo.service.instance = aoodit.com
/Azure Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV:    google.service.instance = aoodev.com
```

**Expected Output:**

azure_micro docker_telco  /AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV
  yahoo_mico  yahoo_telco   /AWS Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/QA1
  azure_micro google_telco  /AWS Cloud/Test/Blender/Service/QA1
                            /Azure Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DEV
                            /Azure Cloud/Test/DEMO/Service/DIT

Comment: This oneliner should do the job from a bash terminal  awk -F: {'print $1'} FILENAME |sed 's/^\|$/"/g' | sort | uniq | sed 's/"//g'

Answer (score 1):

You need [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and python module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

This should do it:

```py
paths = [] # Create an empty list of paths
regex = r'^(\/.+\:).*(ms: )(.+), (cs: )(.+)\)$'

with open("logs.txt") as file: # Open your log file
    for line in file:
        if "cs" in line: # If your line has a cs parameter
            result = re.findall(regex, line)[0]
            paths.append(result[2] + " " + result[4] + " " + result[0])
        else:
            paths.append(line.split(":")[0] + ":") # Old way

paths = list(set(paths)) # Convert to set and then back to list to get all unique path only

print(paths)
```

Comment: We had the same idea you could do the same thing except use `r’:\t’` as the split function. It looks like there is websites with `https://`.

Comment: I'm focusing on the very first `:`, just after the AWS path. So there should be no problems.

Comment: Thanks @ggrelet, could you take a look at question again, I have updated some changes to question to refine the expected output.

Comment: I edited my answer @itgeek. If you liked it, please upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @ggrelet   I'm facing this error                                                                                    result = re.findall(regex, line)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: On which line of the Output Log file exactly? Also, which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python version:  2.7.5
Error Line: result = re.findall(regex, line)[0]

Comment: @itgeek I'd like to know which line of your `output.log` file causes the problem, not the line of my code.

Comment: its very first line no. 1

Comment: And what is this line? Can you be more specific or event paste your txt file here: https://pastebin.com/ and send the link?
My code works fine on my side, even in python2.7...

Comment: do we need any changes to regex to print complete value of https ? currently it prints something like google.service.instance = https:

Comment: My code works perfectly fine with your input. I think it is on your side to make it work for you. Currently I use two method to separate the lines. 1- if the word `cs` is in the line, then I assume the line is like the first three lines of your Log File and I use Regex to find all the parts of the line that are of some interest to you. 2- is `cs` is **not** on the line, then the line is like the last four lines of your Log File. And I use the `split()` method on the character `:` to display what you need. Not sure how you encounter `https:` as it's never implied by your initial question.

Comment: @ggrelet How to get rid of IndexError issues.                                                                               It throughs list out of range error at result = re.findall(regex, line)[0]

Answer (score -1):

Does this work:

```
import os
fh = os.open(‘path/to/log’, mode=‘r’)
file_ = fh.readlines()

def parse_paths(file_):
    directories_list = []
    for line in file_:
        path, message = line.split(r‘:\t’)
        directories_list.append(path)
    return directories_list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Open log file as read-only
logFile = open('file.log', 'r')

# To have a nice array with every line of the log file
logLines = logFile.read().split('\n') 

for path in logLines:

    # Divides every line into an array, where line[0] would be the path, and line[1] would have everything after the colon. Then, print it.
    print(path.split(':')[0])
```